# Comparator sorting on a double attribute fails to satisfy its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, comparator

My class implements `Comparator<ClassName>` .

My requirement is to sort the `ArrayList<Hw4b> myList;` in the descending order of a double type field called `rNumber`. I am Invoking `Collections.sort(myList,this);`

I always get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Comparison method violates its general contract!  at
>   java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public int compare(Hw4b o1, Hw4b o2) {
       double r1 = o1.rNumber;
       double r2 = o2.rNumber;
       if(r2 > r1)
          return 1;
       else if(r2 < r1)
          return -1;
       else
          return 0;    
}
```

I am using Java 8

Comment: You may use this function in wrong way. Please refer to [this tutorial for using detail](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution to accomplishing your task using some of the java-8 features.

```
ArrayList <Hw4b> myList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(myList, Comparator.comparingDouble(Hw4b::getrNumber).reversed());
```

this should sort it in descending order by the `rNumber`.

Comment: Works like a charm , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to write the `if` statements for this yourself. Use `Double.compare`:

```
@Override
public int compare(Hw4b o1, Hw4b o2) {
   return Double.compare(o1.rNumber, o2.rNumber);
}
```

To reverse the sort order, swap the order of `o1.rNumber` and `o2.rNumber`.

Java 8 makes these Comparators simple to write on one line:

```
myList.sort((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o2.rNumber, o1.rNumber));
```

Or:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble((Hw4b x) -> x.rNumber).reversed());
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it sorts in ascending order, my requirement is a descending order.

Comment: Maybe `Comparator.comparingDouble(x -> x.rNumber).reversed()`

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get that exception is because you need to handle Double.NaN. as other people suggested, just take advantage of using Double.compare(o1.rNumber, o2.rNumber) rather than write your own compare method for double values.